# Vibrate after a long click

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app and at some point want to give the user ability to long press a view and after a short vibrate do some action.

I have tried `onLongClick` but it is triggered even on a very very short touch. I have read that the wait time cannot be changed; which makes it useless in my case. Am I missing something about that event?

If no, `onTouchEvent` is the only solution I guess. Is there a way to capture a long press with that event?

Comment: Why can't you use [getDownTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getDownTime%28%29) with the MotionEvent to get the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have not enabled long clicks. Please check whether calling the following method helps (taken from [Android View Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLongClickable%28boolean%29)):

> public void setLongClickable (boolean longClickable)